# mysql query does not see null values in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, rabbitmq

I consume messages from Rabbitmq and trying to write to mysql. I read messages like this

`Object.values(JSON.parse(msg.content.toString()))`

I console.log the consumed message as shown below;

```
[
  null,
  '2016-03-06T22:00:00.000Z',
  null,
  null,
  796,
  null,
  'Weekday',
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  'fff2d9b2-2db9-4fea-96e9-7a4ce5cdda7f',
  '2022-09-08T10:42:43.876Z',
  '2022-09-08T13:43:06.000Z',
  'fc0cca6947244bfb546a409a5512d8bd'
]
```

But when write it into mysql, it writes like this
`insert into date_d (day,date,year,month,date_id,quarter,weekend,day_of_week,day_of_year,day_of_month,week_of_year,month_of_year) values (,2015-09-27T21:00:00.000Z,,,635,,Weekday,,,,,,1bbbfb7a-64cc-46a8-bdc8-a`

insert script shown below

```
"insert into date_d (" + res  + ") values (" + Object.values(JSON.parse(msg.content.toString())) + " )"
```

But mysql deletes null values than it gives me below error.

`"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',2015-09-27T21:00:00.000Z,,,635,,Weekday,,,,,,1bbbfb7a-64cc-46a8-bdc8-a7b7a02b3e' at line 1",`

Any help please thanks.

Comment: Well, I would imagine the easiest thing to do is to set up some sort of default value if it is null or just define it as NULL in your insert statement. Ideally you would use some sort of ORM because raw SQL is just an injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: I found a solution to this but it gets error to another things. For example it comes to consumer as a string but it wants to convert to date type. I can't handle with this format types. Is there any solution for this. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Use parameterized queries. You can insert 'null strings' but you _really should not do this_